# Amazon s3 upload from specific url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't have much experience with amazon s3 and cloud services at all, but I have to configure amazon s3. It has to work like this:
-movies can be played only on our site (done)
-movies can be uploaded only from our site (now i can't upload these from our site at all)

[Now my bucket policies look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PeJ6.png)

Of course i have proper url in section aws:Referer.

What do i do wrong so i can't upload movies from my site? When there was no policy that prevents playing movies outside of our site everything worked just fine.

[Error on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKhAJ.png)

Comment: `aws:Referer` is very poor protection. Your policy basically allows anyone to do anything with your bucket and its objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[aws:referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) is primary used for **GET**, not PUT. This is because, as AWS docs explain:

> The Referer header is included in a web browser request when you **select a link** on a web page.

When you do PUT, your request probably does not contain `Referer` header, which results in access denied.

Also `aws:referer` is **very poor protection** and your policy allows anyone to do anything with your bucket, including deleting and uploading objects to it. [AWS warns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html):

> This key should be used carefully. It is **dangerous** to include a publicly known referer header value. Unauthorized parties can use modified or custom browsers to provide any aws:referer value that they choose.

Basically, you can easily spoof a referrer header. It is a standard [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) which you can set yourself.

Comment: Okay, as i see it isn't good idea to use referer. However i have to have public accessible bucket and i want  it as safe as possible. Do you have any other ideas how can i do that? I have to mention that I'm forced to use bubble.io as a tool to build this website, so I'm little bit limited on frontend.

Comment: @DawidStasiak There is no general, bullet-proof solution for your requirement, except proper authentication and authorization of users to your website. This way your content would be visible only when they login to your application. Sadly I don't have experience with bubble, so can't comment on that.